# A Shelah group in ZFC?

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory

In his famous paper ["On a problem of Kurosh, Jonsson groups, and applications"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X08713466) of 1980, Shelah constructed a CH-example of an uncountable group $G$ equal to $A^{6640}$ for any uncountable subset $A\subset G$.

Let us call a group $G$

$\bullet$ *$n$-Shelah* if $G=A^n$ for each subset $A\subset G$ of cardinality $|A|=|G|$;

$\bullet$ *Shelah* if $G$ is $n$-Shelah for some $n\in\mathbb N$;

$\bullet$ *almost Shelah* if for each subset $A\subset G$ of cardinality $|A|=|G|$ there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $A^n=G$;

$\bullet$ *Jonsson* if each subsemigroup $A\subset G$ of cardinality $|A|=|G|$ coincides with $G$.

$\bullet$ *Kurosh* if each subgroup $A\subset G$ of cardinality $|A|=|G|$ coincides with $G$.

It is clear that for any group $G$ the following implications hold:

> finite $\Leftrightarrow$ 1-Shelah $\Rightarrow$ $n$-Shelah $\Rightarrow$ Shelah $\Rightarrow$ almost Shelah $\Rightarrow$ Jonsson $\Rightarrow$ Kurosh.

In the mentioned paper, Shelah constructed a ZFC-example of an uncountable Jonsson group and also a CH-example of an uncountable 6641-Shelah group.

> **Problem 1.** Can an infinite (almost) Shelah group be constructed in ZFC?
>
> **Problem 2.** Find the largest possible $n$ (which will be smaller than [6640](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314007/on-the-number-n-0-in-shelahs-construction-of-a-jonsson-group)) such that each $n$-Shelah group is finite.

[This result](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00012-010-0032-0) of Protasov implies

> **Theorem (Protasov).** Each countable Shelah group is finite.

It is easy to show that each 2-Shelah group is finite.

> **Problem 3.** Is each 3-Shelah group finite?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for the comment. I have corrected the title.

Comment: When creating names for new mathematical objects I would propose to refrain from using weak + name :-)

Comment: @Jan_Ch. Refrain from using "weak" in lieu of "weakly" would already fix the issue.

Comment: @Jan_Ch. Thank you for the comment. In order to fix the problem I have changed "weak" to "almost"

Comment: In general the use of multiple names makes definition not intuitive, and I thank our ancestors to have found many useful intuitive names to many definitions, and coined words that makes them both flexible and intuitive (such as "uniform", etc).

Comment: I think that history will tell us, but there is nothing which is "almost Shelah". You're either Shelah or not at all Shelah. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila This is also a good question: is there an almost Shelah group, which is not Shelah?

Comment: I could be misremembering but what made the examples CH(I don't recall anything relying on CH)?

Comment: @PaulPlummer It is the construction: for every cardinal $\lambda$ with $\lambda^+=2^\lambda$ Shelah constructs a 6643-Shelah group of cardinality $\lambda^+$. But by the Easton's Theorem cardinals $\lambda$ with $\lambda^+=2^\lambda$ need not exist in ZFC. On the other hand,  such a cardinal $\lambda$ (namely $\lambda=\aleph_0$ exists under CH.

Comment: Ah okay I see. I do seem to remember that n-Shelah $\aleph_1$ groups exist was done in the paper too, but I could be misremembering (I guess I should look in the paper

Comment: Taras, does Shelah's construction rely on regular $\lambda$, or did you not mean Easton's Theorem in your previous comment?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais No, Shelah construction seems to hold for any infinite cardinal $\lambda$ with $\lambda^+=2^\lambda$. I mentioned the Easton's Theorem to argume that ZFC does not imply the existence of a cardinal $\lambda$ with $\lambda^+=2^\lambda$. Or such a cardinal always exists?

Comment: Easton's Theorem only applies to regular cardinals. To have $2^\lambda>\lambda^+$ everywhere, including at singular $\lambda$, is much more difficult and requires some very large cardinal hypotheses: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2944324

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.11155.pdf), Mark Poor and Assaf Rinot construct a ZFC-example of a $10120$-Shelah group $G$ of cardinality $|G|=\lambda^+$, where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary regular сardinal.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure what makes an answer to a question with several problems of very variable difficulty a good answer :)

Anyway:

> there's no "3-Shelah" group. That is, every infinite group admits a subset $W$ such that $W^3\neq G$ and $|W|=G$. (Actually one can arrange $W\cup W^2\cup W^3\neq G$.)

Let $G$ be an infinite group. Let $A$, by Zorn, be a maximal subset such that $1\notin A\cup A^2\cup A^3$. Denote by $\langle A\rangle$ the subgroup generated by $A$, and $G^{(6)}$ the subgroup of $G$ generated by $\{g^6:g\in G\}$; clearly $G^{(6)}$ is normal in $G$.

For every $g\in G\smallsetminus A$, the maximality implies that $$1\in (A\cup\{g\})\cup(A\cup\{g\})^2\cup (A\cup\{g\})^3.$$ Since $1\notin A\cup A^2\cup A^3$, this means that 
$$1\in \{g\}\cup Ag\cup gA\cup\{g^2\}\cup  A^2g\cup AgA\cup gA^2\cup g^2A\cup gAg\cup Ag^2\cup\{g^3\}.$$
Hence one of the following holds: $g=1$ or $g^2=1$ $g^3=1$ or $g\in A^{-1}$, or $g^2\in A^{-1}$ or $g\in (A^2)^{-1}$.

Hence, $g^6\in \langle A\rangle$ for all $g\in G$; equivalently, $G^{(6)}\subset \langle A\rangle$.
In $G/G^{(6)}$, every element satisfies $x^6=1$. Since groups of exponent 6 are solvable, it follows that either $G=G^{(6)}$, or $G$ has a normal subgroup of index 2 or 3. In the last two cases, we define this subgroup as $W$. Otherwise, $\langle A\rangle=G$, that is, $A$ generates $G$. In particular, since $G$ is infinite, $|A|=|G|$, so we put $A=W$.

Comment: What about a set $A=A^{-1}$ with $A^3\ne G$?

Comment: Can you please explain why the subgroup $B$ is normal?

Comment: $B$ is not always normal, it's fixed now.

Comment: About multiple questions in a single thread, see this discussion: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3458/more-than-1-question-in-a-thread/3459.

Comment: The argument does not adapt to the additional requirements $A=A^{-1}$, or $1\in A$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial answer to Problem 2 about the largest number $n$ such that every $n$-Shelah group is finite. The main result of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.01750) implies that this number $n<36$, at least under the Continuum Hypothesis. Combined with the inequality $n\ge 3$ proved by @YCor in his answer, we have the (sufficiently narrow) lower and upper bounds $3\le n<36$ for the number $n$.

It seems that $36$ is the smallest number $n$ that can be achieved in the Shelah's construction of an $n$-Shelah group. So, $6640$ in the original Shelah's construction of a $6640$-Shelah group can be lowered to $36$ but not less.

Comment: To clarify: this is a partial result due to the fact it's constructed in ZFC+CH and not ZFC?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I had in mind that this is a partial answer because it only imposes the upper bound $n\le 36$ for that number $n$ and we still do not know the exact value of the largest number $n$ such that every $n$-Shelah group is finite. We know only that $3\le n<36$. Another reason for a partial answer is that this upper bound depends on some set-theoretic assumptions, so it is not a ZFC-result (exactly as you have written).

Comment: Ok, thanks, that helps.