# Can a Shelah semigroup be commutative?

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, universal-algebra

A semigroup $S$ is called

$\bullet$ *$n$-Shelah* for a positive integer $n$ if $S=A^n$ for any subset $A\subset S$ of cardinality $|A|=|S|$;

$\bullet$ *Shelah* if $S$ is $n$-Shelah for some $n\in\mathbb N$.

> **Question.** Can an infinite Shelah semigroup be commutative?

This problem was motivated by the following results:

**Theorem ([Shelah, 1980](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X08713466)).** For any infinite cardinal $\lambda$ with $\lambda^+=2^\lambda$ there exists a group $G$ of cardinality $|G|=\lambda^+$, which is a $6640$-Shelah semigroup.

**Theorem ([Banakh, 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.01750)).** For any cardinal $\lambda$ with $\lambda^+=2^\lambda$, every group $H$ of cardinality $|H|\le\lambda$ is a subgroup of a $36$-Shelah group $G$ of cardinality $|G|=\lambda^+$.

**Corollary.** Under CH there exists a Shelah semigroup of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

**Theorem ([Protasov, 2010](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00012-010-0032-0)).** Each countable Shelah semigroup is finite.

**Theorem (folklore?).** A commutative group is finite iff it is a Shelah semigroup.

**Proposition ([@YCor, 2018](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313516/a-shelah-group-in-zfc)).** A group is finite iff it is a 3-Shelah semigroup.

**Theorem ([Todorcevic, 1987](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485890491)).** There is a commutative binary operation $\cdot:X\times X\to X$ of a set $X$ of cardinality $|X|=\aleph_1$ such that $X=A^2:=\{ab:a,b\in A\}$ for any uncountable subset $A\subset X$.

---

**Added in Edit**, after reading the answer of Keith Kearnes who referred to [the paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02944951) of Ralph McKenzie who studied Jonsson semigroups.

Let us recall that a semigroup $S$ is *Jonsson* if $S=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A^n$ for any subset $A\subset S$ of cardinality $|A|=|S|$. It is clear that each Shelah semigroup is Jonsson.

> **Theorem ([McKenzie, 1971](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02944951)).** A Jonsson semigroup $S$ of infinite cardinality $\kappa$ is a non-commutative group if $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)>\omega$ or $2^{<\kappa}\le\kappa$.

McKenzie asked in [his paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02944951) if this theorem remains true without set-theoretic assumptions.

> **Problem (McKenzie, 1971).** Is each infinite Jonsson semigroup a group?

Is this problem of McKenzie still open?

Comment: My easy construction is not worth being called a theorem. Also Shelah produced Shelah semigroups (that are groups) of cardinal $\aleph_1$ in ZFC.

Comment: @YCor Ok. Then how to call your result? It is interesting anyway and should be mentioned in this context.

Comment: @YCor Are you sure that Shelah constructed a Shelah semigroup in ZFC? It is not stated this way in his paper. His ZFC-Theorem 2.9 is formulated differently and does not mention any $n_0$ which appear explicitly in the formulation of his CH-Theorem 2.1  Moreover, proving his Theorem C on non-topologizable groups, Shelah proves this theorem only under CH. Why? If he would produce a Shelah group in ZFC, why CH-appears in the application of this theorem to the problem of topologizability?

Comment: From the MR review of Shelah's paper: *The author constructs some remarkable infinite groups, notably "Jónsson groups'', that is, groups of uncountable cardinality containing no proper subgroups (or better: no proper subsemigroup) of the same cardinality. One construction works for all successor cardinals if we assume the generalized continuum hypothesis; a variant works for $\aleph_1$ with no set-theoretic assumptions.* https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=579953 But maybe this refers to being Jonsson, and not the more precise exponent fact? I don't have the paper actually.

Comment: @YCor I read the ``variant" mentioned in MR-review as the fact that the ZFC-result of Shelah yields only a Jonsson semigroup, but not a Shelah semigroup (whose construction is different and do required additional assumptions like CH).

Comment: OK thanks. Side note: Todorcevic can be stated more in the style of Shelah's result: "There exists a 2-Shelah magma of cardinal $\aleph_1$". (Being $n$-Shelah, for a semigroup, only refers to the magma structure.)

Comment: @YCor I thought about writing this way, but in this case I should recall the definition of a magma and state the Shelah property for magmas, which will disctract potential solver from this question (semigroups are much more known comparing to magmas, for which moreover there are many alternative names like quasigroups).

Comment: I didn't mean to rewrite your question, it was just a restatement (I was initially puzzled by the dissymmetry of formulation "Shelah constructs a semigroup of cardinal $\aleph_1$" vs "For every set of cardinal $\aleph_1$ there is a structure of ...").

Comment: @YCor You are right. The formulation of Todorcevic's Theorem was akward. Now I reformulated in the ``existential" form.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An infinite Shelah semigroup must be a Jonsson semigroup (meaning that it is an infinite semigroup whose proper subsemigroups have lesser power). Therefore the following paper answers the question asked on this page:

McKenzie, Ralph
 
On semigroups whose proper subsemigroups have lesser power.
 
Algebra Universalis 1 (1971), no. 1, 21-25.

McKenzie proves that 
(1) the only commutative Jonsson semigroups are the generalized cyclic groups, and
(2) under GCH every Jonsson semigroup is the underlying semigroup of a group.

To reiterate and overexplain: infinite + Shelah + commutative implies infinite + Jonsson + commutative implies generalized cyclic. But the generalized cyclic groups are not Shelah. Thus infinite + Shelah + commutative semigroups do not exist.